# select distinct of different date in varchar format and display/group them in month and year only

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In one of my db table, there is a column `FinalDate` which will store the date and the data type is not `datetime` but `varchar`. I would like to write a query that I can select distinct `FinalDate` and group/display like `Jun 2012`, `Jul 2012`.

Values for the `FinalDate` column would be something like below:

```
20120213  
20120225  
20120218  
20120306  
20120320
```

So, how I can write a query to select distinct of the `FinalDate` and display them in:

```
Feb 2012  
Mar 2012
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @a table (d varchar(8))
insert into @a Values ('20120213'),('20120225'),('20120218'),('20120306'),('20120320');


Select FinalDate
from
(
select Distinct 
 --DateName(Month,d)+' '+CAST(Datepart(yy,d) as Varchar(4)) as FinalDate
   SubString(DateName(Month,d),1,3)+' '+CAST(Datepart(yy,d) as Varchar(4)) as FinalDate
,Datepart(yy,d) as yy,Datepart(mm,d) as mm
from
(Select  CAST(d as datetime) as d from @a) a
) b
Order by yy,mm
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (t VARCHAR(8))
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES 
    ('20120213'),
    ('20120225'),
    ('20120218'),
    ('20120306'),
    ('20120320')

SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, t), 3) + ' ' + y
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
          t = CAST(LEFT(t, 6) + '01' AS DATETIME)
        , y = LEFT(t, 4)
    FROM @temp
) t
ORDER BY t
```

**Output:**

```
Feb 2012
Mar 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
SELECT 
Count (SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(12), CONVERT(date, StringDate,112),113),4,12)) as counts,
 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(12), CONVERT(date, StringDate,112),113),4,12) from Employees
 group by SUBSTRING(CONVERT(char(12), CONVERT(date, StringDate,112),113),4,12)
```

output

```
counts  (No column name)
1   Apr 1992 
1   Aug 1992 
1   Jan 1994 
1   Mar 1994 
1   May 1992 
1   May 1993 
1   Nov 1994 
2   Oct 1993
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CTE based approach. Replace [[[TABLE_NAME]]] with the actual name of the table that contains the FinalDate field. I did the processing in the final select rather than inside of the CTE to prevent any chance of SQL Server performing the processing on filtered out (non-seq 1) rows.

```
WITH a AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(FinalDate, 6) ORDER BY FinalDate) seq, FinalDate 
    FROM [[[TABLE_NAME]]]
) SELECT LEFT(DATENAME(mm, FinalDate), 3) + ' ' + LEFT(FinalDate, 4)
FROM a
WHERE seq = 1
```